# (Perhaps dumb) question about Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: monte-carlo

I am experimenting with Monte Carlo simulations and have a question about the applicability of the method to my particular problem.

In this problem, I have a parameter $\phi$ which is normally distributed. I am then running a number of simulations to randomly generate values for $\phi$ that follow this normal distribution (using SMath, which is just like Mathcad). So far so good; however, where I am having a problem conceptually is the next step.

In order to solve my problem, I then need to take the randomly generated values of $\phi$, and use a transformation function which is non-linear to calculate a new parameter $N_y$. The equation for $N_y$ involves exponents and squaring a term. I then use this new parameter to calculate the final answer. If it helps, it is the bearing capacity problem for soils, where the ultimate bearing capacity $Q$ for sands is
$$\begin{aligned}
Q &= \frac{B\gamma N_y}{2} \\
N_y &= (N_q-1)\text{tan}(1.4\phi) \\
N_q &= \exp(\pi\text{tan}(\phi))\tan^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\phi}{2}\right),
\end{aligned}$$
where $B$ is footing width and constant, and $\gamma$ is soil unit weight and also constant.

When I check my results as I go, what I have noticed is that the expected value of $N_y$ should be approximately $26.2$ (when calculated directly using the mean $\phi$ which in this example is $33$ degrees); however, the mean of $N_y$ when using the randomly generated values of $\phi$ is $31.3$ after $10,000$ simulations. Of course, this means that the expected result differs from the result obtained from the Monte Carlo simulation. In thinking about this, the transformation of $\phi$ to $N_y$ uses a non-linear equation therefore this difference should not be unexpected. What I don't know however, is whether this means the Monte Carlo simulation is not applicable for this particular problem because of this. I have seen the simpler Point Estimate Method used to solve the same problem, and I noticed this non-linear transformation should also affect the result of that but I have seen several published solutions using that method so it made me wonder...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) You can use MathJaX to make your question more legible. (2) You already understand that the expectation of a transform of a random variable is usually *not* the same as the transform of the expectation if the transform is nonlinear, that is good. (3) Whether this means that your MC simulation is not applicable to your particular problem will depend on what your MC simulation does, what your problem is, and what question you are addressing. Can you please add this information?

Comment: How exactly have you arithmetically calculated the 26.2? The answer to your question is that MCMC can definitely simulate a result, and you should check your arithmetic. Jensen's inequality is the result your looking for - which establishes that $E(f(X)) < f(E(X))$ if $f$ is strictly concave.

Comment: A tangent curve has many discontinuities. At best, you can make the likelihood of $\phi$ spanning a discontinuity very low so that you can approximate a result, otherwise you can't expect any valid numerical finding.

Comment: whether the simulation matches the 'point estimate' method depends on your (MC) variance (and correct implementation). If published results seem to use the point estimate then that would *suggest* that the variance is sufficiently low (for the required accuracy). checks: does your MC Phi have the correct mean/variance? please add your checks and values into the question (eg Phi has mean var...)

Comment: To answer a few questions:

- The MC simulation is used to generate random values of Phi that follow a normal distribution.

- Ny is arithmetically calculated as 26.2 using the equations I provided for a Phi value of 33 which is the mean. So first Nq is calculated using Phi=33, then Ny.

- I have indeed checked that my MC Phi has the expected mean and variance, but only after I run a sufficiently large number of trials (which in this case was 10,000).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many commenters have stated (and as you yourself noted in the question), the issue is that
$$E(Q) = E(g(\phi)) \neq g(E(\phi)),$$
in general. The only situations where equality will hold is

1. $\phi$ is a "degenerate" random variable (e.g., $\phi$ is constant with $\text{Var}(\phi) = 0$)
2. $g$ is a linear function.

Neither of these principles hold here. This means that you cannot use a point estimate for $\phi$, like the expected value $\hat\phi = E(\phi)$ and then compute $\hat Q_\times = g(\hat\phi)$. This quantity doesn't tell us anything particularly interesting about $Q$!

You say in the question

> What I don't know however, is whether this means the Monte Carlo simulation is not applicable for this particular problem because of this.

But no! **Monte Carlo is absolute applicable here** and is one of the easiest ways to get the *correct* answer for $E(Q)$. The other benefit of using Monte Carlo is that, in addition to finding the correct value for $E(Q)$, **we can also easily find the entire distribution for $Q$**. This can be useful for estimating things like *intervals* within which $Q$ is likely to fall.

---

### Simulations

Suppose that $\phi \sim N(33, 3^2)$. Since $B$ and $\gamma$ were not specified, I am setting them to unity for these simulations, but they can be easily changed in the R code.

Note the histogram, which gives the entire Monte Carlo distribution for $Q$, which describes not just the expected value but the range of reasonable values.

[image]

```
# Fill in B and gamma with better values
B <- 1
gamma <- 1
g <- function(phi, B, gamma){
  phi <- 2*pi*phi/360
  Nq <- exp(pi*tan(phi))*tan(pi/4 + phi/2)^2
  Ny <- (Nq - 1)*tan(1.4*phi)
  Q <- B * gamma * Ny / 2
}

# Wrong approach using the mean of phi
Qhat_point <- g(33, B, gamma)
# > Qhat_point = 13.08285

# Monte Carlo approach
Nmc <- 10000
Q_mc <- rep(NA, Nmc)
for(m in 1:Nmc){
  phi_m <- rnorm(1, 33, 3)
  Q_mc[m] <- g(phi_m)
}
mean(Q_mc)
# > mean(Q_mc) = 15.17342

hist(Q_mc, breaks=30, main="Simulated distribution of Q")
abline(v=mean(Q_mc), lwd=3, col='orange', lty=2)
```

Comment: Hi @knrumsey, thank you so much! The reason I wanted to do MC was indeed to get the distribution for E[Q], because I can then use those to compare against a threshold value to calculate a probability of failure and reliability for the system. 

I ran my own simulations with SMath using unity for B and Gamma like you did (and Phi = 33 with a standard deviation of 3), and I am also getting a mean Q_mc value of 15.2 which is promising :-)

Comment: That said, I am still a bit hung up on the non-linear transformation function to calculate Ny from Phi and its implications. In this particular example, is it OK to run MC simulations as long as the parameter that is being randomly generated (Phi) has the correct statistics, even though the transformation function is non-linear? Thanks again!

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're hung up on? The answer is YES it is okay. This is exactly the type of problem where MC is so useful! This is the whole point of using MC. 

Responding to your first comment... this is the distribution for $Q$ -- $E(Q)$ is just a constant and it doesn't really make sense to talk about the distribution of $E(Q)$.

Comment: Maybe "hung up" is not the right word, more like confused and trying to understand better :-) And I apologize for using the incorrect terminology; I indeed meant distribution of Q, not E[Q].  

In my head, I was expecting the mean of Q_mc to more closely match what you termed "Qhat_point". But I think I am starting to understand why that is not a problem (and in fact should be expected).